# How can I permanently rebind keys?

Tags: keymap, key-bindings

**How can I permanently rebind keys?**

I'd like to rebind `C-i`, `C-j`, `C-k`, and `C-l` to act like the arrow keys.  However, when using

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-l") 'forward-char)
```

it will only do so for the session; the bindings don't persist after restarting Emacs.

Is there some way to automatically do this every time on startup or via a config file or something?

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE.  As a general rule, please do a little background research before posting a question -- googling `emacs config file` will return the [manual page for the init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) as the first hit.

Comment: Well, I upvoted both the question and @Dan's comment. (I'm not completely sure why, but it felt right. ;-)).  Such a newbie question should be OK for this site, I think. But such a comment is also helpful, to try to steer people to **ask Emacs first**. IOW, the question is a natural one, and we cannot fault newbies for not yet knowing how to ask Emacs itself for the answer.

Comment: @Drew That was the exact reasoning why I added the answer. We want this site to be useful to all emacs users: newbie to advanced. No one should go back unanswered as long as the question is emacs related :)

Comment: @kaushalmodi: And I'm glad to see that someone else (you, most likely) upvoted the question, which had several downvotes initially). It's not a *great* question, but it is certainly a reasonable question for a newbie to have.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who posted or upvoted for the pretty kind welcome to the community, despite the newbie question. 

I'm indeed a first-time emacs user (who knew), and had the great urge to change the keybindings at ~30% into the help-with-tutorial.

While Dan's post (as well as other posts here) clearly solves the problem, I was for some reason stuck with always googling sth around key bindings, and although learning lots of other things in the process, I couldn't find a working answer.

I hope this helps anyone who might get stuck in his googling/thought process in the same way as me.

Answer (score 7):

As @Dan mentioned in his comment to your question above, you can do that by putting your customizations in a config file like `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.

**But** I would recommend not overriding the `C-i` `C-j` `C-k` `C-l` keys as they serve some core functions like joining lines, killing text, etc.

Try out `evil-mode` instead if you need vim-style navigation.

I got used to `C-b` `C-n` `C-p` `C-f` keys by installing `hardcore-mode`.

Comment: +1 re: suggestion to rely only on `C-b`, `C-n`, `C-p` and `C-f` to move cursor.  Before I got used to these shortcuts, I didn't quite appreciate just how much faster you can manipulate text/code/etc when your hands don't have to leave the "default position".  

(Though one of the temporary side effects is that you'll occasionally open a slew of new windows in your web-browser)

Comment: That's an interesting use of "default" finger position. Usually people mean the "home" row, i.e., "JKL;".

Answer (score 2):

I use a similar cursor movement layout to what you want (IJKL, making for an inverse T), and absolutely love it. I got the initial idea from Xah Lee's [ErgoEmacs keybinding](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/ergonomic_emacs_keybinding.html) project, now moved to Github: https://ergoemacs.github.io/

The only drawback is that when I first start using a new mode, I may have to clean up its keymap to follow my pattern, but this is fairly rare and a one-time-only operation.

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683425/globally-override-key-binding-in-emacs useful for never needing to modify other keymaps to prevent conflicts.

Comment: Ah, so that's why ErgoEmacs uses a minor mode too. I thought it was too heavy weight for just a few keys, didn't think that it would also fix conflicts with other major modes.

On the other hand, this way I get a closer look at each new mode and have to decide whether there are any of its keybindings that I should adopt into my scheme. :-)